# NodeJs and Google Colab

Tags: jupyter, google-colaboratory, google-api-nodejs-client

I need to pass an array/or parameters from NodeJS to a notebook of Colab or Notebook of Jupiter. 
How I can do that? 
There is possible some solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. run nodejs as webserver (easiest modules  http or expressjs ) and publish your arrays/parameters as json (JSON.encode). If you dont have server, you can use whatsmyip services to find your place ip address, and adjusting your router (modem) to point ports to your computer.
   in the collab you can use

   ```
   !wget http://myip:8080/myarrays -O my.json
   ```

   to save or urllib.request.urlretrieve to retrive.
2. run nodejs in the colab and webserver/socket/file implementations works.